# XPath expression with where statement

Tags: java, xpath, expression

I have xml and I want to get, using xpath expression, text from Text node only if Text_2 contains elements. Is there any possibility? I couldn't find out any.

```
<List>
   <Response>
    <Node>
       <SomeNode>
        <Text>text</Text>
        <Text_1>text_1</Text_1>
        <Text_2 value_1="some value 1" value_2="some value 2" />
       </SomeNode>
    </Node>
    </Response>
</List>
```

I tried to get Text_2 elements using //*[@value_1] but I stuck and do not have any other idea

Comment: `//SomeNode[boolean(Text_2/@*)]/Text` is a vague attempt, i am not 100% sure that `boolean(Text_2/@*)` reliably checks for the existence of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Your text says "want to get, using xpath expression, text from Text node only if Text_2 contains elements", with your given sample that would be `//SomeNode[Text_2/*]/Text`. For some reasons I don't understand, however, in your sample the `Text_2` element doesn't have any child elements.